# javascript NaN issue

Tags: javascript, nan

i need to write a code abbreviate the words greater than 10 letters to be as this : localiztion -> l10n. i used javascript to do this but a NaN error.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Way Too Long Words</title>
</head>
<body>

       <input type="text">
       <button>abbreviate</button>
       <div id="result"></div>

<script>

    var word = document.querySelector('input').value.split('');

    document.querySelector("button").onclick = function () {
    "use strict";
    var theResult = word[0] + word.slice(1, -1).length + word[word.length - 1];

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = theResult;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to overcome this issue

Answer (score 0):

I see two major problems with your code as it stands:

1. You currently only set the value of `word` once, when the document is loaded. You want this to happen every time the button is clicked.
2. You don't currently check that `word` is longer than 10 letters, and try to calculate `theResult` regardless.

The combination of the two problems above means that `word` is set to an empty string as soon as the page loads, and clicking the button will always result in `theResult` being `NaN`.

Comment: i tried to place the js in a separate file an called it in the html file <script src="main.js"></script> and includes in it the code:
var word = document.querySelector('input').value;

document.querySelector("button").onclick = function () {
    "use strict";
    var theResult = word[0] + word.slice(1, -1).length + word[word.length - 1];
    
    if (word.length > 10) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = theResult;
    }
};

Comment: @MohamedMahmoudElkassas Splitting the code out into a separate file won't change how it runs, but is a good habit to get into for larger chunks of code. You've kind of solved issue 2, but the person using the page may not know why they can't see a result (this may or may not be an issue for you, I don't know). You haven't solved issue 1 though - the line of code defining `word` needs to be inside your click-handling function, otherwise you're still only setting the value of `word` once, rather than every time the button is clicked.